# Immutablility nature

Tags: immutability

When two same objects are referred by two different variables.
Then the output is true(when object is in range -5 to 256) when identity operation is used on them and it's false when it is out of range of -5 to 256

I thought for any two same immutable objects their ID's would be same but it's not. Why?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is only the case for objects (arrays are objects), for primitive values an assignment to another variable will always copy the value.